# pylint can't find QtCore in PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt, pylint, spyder

I recently installed Python(x,y) for spyder and the PyQt4 support.  I selected pylint during the install process, and loaded up a script from the code resources for 'Rapid GUI Development with Python & Qt4'... specifically the first simple 'alert.pyw' from chapter 4.

Pylint is saying that this is an error:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import (QTime, QTimer, Qt, SIGNAL)
```

...and here is the error message:

```
[E0611]19: No name 'QtCore' in module 'PyQt4'
```

...but in both the regular Python interpreter (2.7.3) and the ipython interpreter (0.13) I can type in:

```
from PyQt<tab>4.QtC<tab>ore
```

and the auto-complete seems to find it just fine.

Is there some way to get pylint set up so it sees things that are obviously there, or am I better off disabling pylint and going back to pyflakes or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like it may be related to the pylint issue raised [here](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2009-July/023864.html), although it is from quite some time ago. What versions of PyQt4 and pylint are you using?

If it is the same issue, then changing the imports to something like:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4.QtCore import (QTime, QTimer, Qt, SIGNAL)
```

may stop the "error" messages.

Comment: PyQt4 4.9.4 & pylint 0.26-1... both of which are pretty 'fresh' compared to the versions around the time of those posts.  Not sure I get what changing the order of importing QtGui and QtCore should make with the way pylint tells if QtCore is in PyQt4 or not.  But it does seem to work...

Comment: Linking only in the answer can mean its no longer available later. In this case the first link is dead. The relevant parts/facts should be represented independently of links working.

Comment: @DannyStaple. Not sure what you mean. I gave all the relevant facts in my answer - i.e. a possible way to "fix" the problem. I don't think I ever really found a directly relevant link - the two I gave were only possibly related issues. If you're still having the same problems, I would suggest doing a new search with whatever error message you're now getting, as that would likely produce more up-to-date information (such as [this](https://lists.logilab.org/pipermail/python-projects/2013-January/003384.html) - which seems to be a follow up by the OP).